# Why does Neo choose Trinity over the World?

Tags: the-matrix

I mean if you leave out the dramatic effect of it in the movie as whole. I would like to think that Neo's choice to save Trinity rather than the whole World seemed quite dumb. I mean, even after saving her at that moment, he could not save her in the machine city. What could possibly have urged him to save 1 person over the World even if he loves her?

Comment: If you leave out dramatic effects of the whole movie, you're not left with much.

Comment: I thought of matrix as a very logical movie... hence the statement

Comment: @MozenRath logical? Hope that was sarcasm :)

Comment: Maybe he's just hot for brunettes in PVC...

Comment: Hmm... a world full of @#%^s or a hot leggy brunette girlfriend... I'm thinking...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The key point here is that Neo hasn't been offered the choice "Save Trinity or save the human race".  He's been offered the choice "Save Trinity or save a few other people, handpicked, while the machines massacre 99.9% of the free humans."  And option B involves collaborating with the Architect, who represents everything Neo despises about the machines.

*Both* choices are repugnant, impossible.  But he only has the Architect's word for it that option B is necessary, and that the world would end if it wasn't taken.  As it turns out, this was wrong.  (Neo had reason to think so, too - clearly the Oracle didn't agree that no better alternative was possible.)

Comment: I dont think neo knew that they were attacking zion in reloaded

Comment: So meaning that neo was tried to be manipulated by the words on oracle and architect?

Comment: @MozenRath: Neo didn't know at first, but the Architect pretty much flat out states that with every previous One they've wiped out Zion and rebuilt it with the One and a small selection of survivors. Neo can easily guess what's happening after that. (The big unpleasant surprise of the movie, after all, is supposed to be that Zion is just a bigger trap.  Redpills always happen - the Matrix can't work unless humans are free enough that some reject it - so the machines let them build a real-world city... and they know where it is.

Comment: And yes, I think it's pretty strongly implied that the Architect and the Oracle are opponents.  The Architect is all rules and no empathy and wants the Matrix to be an unfeeling human-trap; the Oracle is all empathy and no rules and wants freedom for humans and rogue software alike.

Comment: I don't think it is so much that they are opponents as that they are different facets of the matrix system in dynamic tension.  The matrix couldn't work without both of them.

Comment: @WilliamBSwift: True; that's why I said 'opponents' not 'enemies'.  Neither is trying to kill the other directly; it's more like opposing debate teams.  Only the audience is easily persuaded, and has live ammo.

Comment: @Tynam - it's more like two sides of the same coin. The Oracle & The Architect are the yin & yang of the system... two opposing ends of the same spectrum.

Answer (score 4):

As [Tynam](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12724/2565) states, Neo despising the Architect (due to his previous indoctrination by Morpheus!) played a role, but it is safe to assume that the previous Ones weren't exactly the biggest fan of the machines. Thus we cannot take any of that as a logical explanation for his deviation from his previous versions (the double meaning of "versions" is *not* intended).

If we can trust the Architect (I believe we can very safely assume he wouldn't knowingly state the untrue!) Trinity is the only factor that Neo hasn't in common with its predecessors; The only reason for him to choose the "apocalypse". I'm sorry I have to pull out the same argument [twice in a day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12715/2565), but that's the plain answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is not either/or. It is about balance. The unknown variable in the equation is "what happens if Neo does not chose the Architect's choice?" To choice the Architect's choice is a given, to not choose it is an unknown. The influence in Neo's choice is Trinity; he chooses Trinity, not Zion. And in choosing Trinity, other unknowns (variables) influence a different outcome. The Oracle said later in the film, that no vision was available for a decision that could not be understood. The Architect could only understand the one decision, the decision that had already been made previous times in history and therefore could see beyond it. But could not understand the decision that Neo made and therefore could not see beyond it.....too many variables.